# SQLAlchemy: How do you delete multiple rows without querying

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a table that has millions of rows. I want to delete multiple rows via an in clause.  However, using the code:

```
session.query(Users).filter(Users.id.in_(subquery....)).delete()
```

The above code will query the results, and then execute the delete.  I don't want to do that. I want speed.

I want to be able to execute (yes I know about the session.execute):`Delete from users where id in ()`

**So the Question:** How can I get the best of two worlds, using the ORM? Can I do the delete without hard coding the query?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yep! You can call `delete()` on the table object with an associated where clause.

Something like this:

```
stmt = Users.__table__.delete().where(Users.id.in_(subquery...))
```

(and then don't forget to execute the statement: `engine.execute(stmt)`)

[source](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TableClause.delete)

Comment: Didnt the question ask about using the ORM? This uses SQAlchemy Core syntax. Just an FYI I guess.

Answer (score 49):

To complete [dizzy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39774354/5251001)'s answer:

```
delete_q = Report.__table__.delete().where(Report.data == 'test')
db.session.execute(delete_q)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 31):

The below solution also works, if developers do not want to execute a plain vanilla query.

```py
session.query(Users).filter(Users.id.in_(subquery....)).delete(synchronize_session=False)
```

Comment: What is that `synchronize_session=False` for?

Comment: @NamGVU Here is the explanation from the documentation:

False - don’t synchronize the session. This option is the most efficient and is reliable once the session is expired, which typically occurs after a commit(), or explicitly using expire_all(). Before the expiration, objects that were updated or deleted in the database may still remain in the session with stale values, which can lead to confusing results.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#selecting-a-synchronization-strategy

Answer (score 19):

## New syntax (1.4 version and above)

```py
from sqlalchemy import delete

statement = delete(User).where(User.id.in_(...))
session.execute(statement)
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/dml.html?highlight=delete