# Bulk Deleting Records in SQLAlchemy Using List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bulk-delete

Is there a way to pass something like a list of dictionaries and delete records in bulk using SQLAlchemy? It is possible to use `bulk_insert_mappings` for inserts and `bulk_update_mappings` for updates, but what about deletes?

Basically, I have a table with a composite key. I want to be able to delete multiple records in this table in bulk by passing in the relevant mappings. The mappings would look something like this,

```
[{'main_id': 09901, 'sub_id': 88002}, {'main_id': 09902, 'sub_id': 88006}]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I have been using this to bulk delete data in a table with a single key,

```
self.session.query(model).filter(model.key.in_(entries)).delete(synchronize_session=False)
self.session.commit()
```

Comment: Here you have alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773560/sqlalchemy-how-do-you-delete-multiple-rows-without-querying